# Remove everything in a string after a second space if there is one

Tags: java, string

Lets say I have this text: `Thundering Blow I`. What I need is something that makes it look like `Thundering Blow` - Removing the roman number at the end of the string.

I have tried `trim()` and some `substring()` methods but they all keep returning: `Thundering Blow I` back to me. Maybe it could remove everything after a `I` in the string? Would also be fine, but I cant seem to find a way to fix it.

Comment: So, where's the code you tried? (with substring. trim removes white space, and "I" is not white space)

Comment: Please show us several examples including positives and negatives.

Comment: You need to be more specific. I'm pretty sure what you want is not removing anything after a second space, but rather removing the roman number in last position if any.

Comment: What about *Thundering Blow returning IV*?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need this, removes all characters after second space

```
String s = "Thundering Blow I";
int k = s.indexOf(" ", s.indexOf(" ") + 1);
String res = s.substring(0,k);
System.out.println(res);
```

Comment: @DanielHoller then why don't you accept the answer.

Comment: Would this work for a phrase of more than 3 words?  What about if the roman numeral be missing?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen He never asked that .

Comment: Then the OP is misleading.  What does it matter that the last word be a roman numeral?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen It removes all characters after the second space. Doesn't matter whether it's roman or some other characters. P.S that's what he asked

Comment: @sameerasy Indeed, that's what OP asked in the title, but we can tell from the text that he might have oversimplified his problem. He's actually leading answers towards one solution which is not necessarily the best for his exact problem. But without more information about his problem space, we can't know for sure.

Comment: @wajeeh answer is way "better": it removes the last word. Your answer just keeps the first two words and doesn't cope with consecutive spaces.

Answer (score 5):

```
String newStr = s.substring(0, s.lastIndexOf(" "));
```

This is the whole code:

```
String s = "ThunderingI";
s = s.trim();
int ind = s.lastIndexOf(" ");
if (ind > 0) {
    s = s.substring(0, ind).trim();
}
System.out.println(s);
```

Comment: Good effort but this removes all characters only if there are 2 spaces in the string. What if the string has many more spaces?

Comment: @sameerasy no, it removes the last word.

Comment: @sameerasy `lastIndexOf(String)` returns the last index of the string or -1

Answer (score 2):

You can split the string then concatenate a new string with index 0 and 1.
Easiest solution :)..

```
String[] tempArray = orgStr.split(" ");
String newStr = tempArray[0] + " " + tempArray[1];
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try this.

```
        String a = "Thundering Blow I";
        String[] b = a.split(" ");
        System.out.println(b[0]+" "+b[1]);
```

Answer (score 1):

This will remove a single Roman numeral from the end of a string, if it exists:

```
String input = "Thundering Blow returning MMXVI";
input = input.replaceAll("\\s[CDILMVX]*$", "");
```

`MMXVI` is 2016 in Roman numerals in case you are wondering.